# Get Woocommerce product by slug

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I have a function to grab products by their category and return specific data about them using their category slug like so:

```
$itemArgs = array( 
    'post_type' => 'product', 
    'posts_per_page' => 1000, 
    'product_cat' => $request['id'], 
    'include_children' => false 
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $itemArgs );
if ( $loop->have_posts() ) : while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
  //DO STUFF
endwhile; endif;
```

Which works fantastically. What I need now is to get a product by its own slug. Where the one above might get every product for "Cookies" category, this one should return just the "Chocolate Chip" product.

I've tried replacing `'product_cat'` with `'slug'` and `'product_slug'` but those don't appear to work. This seems like a fairly straightforward thing to do... there's documentation on finding a product by 48 different properties... slug is not one for some reason. I just get the entirety of the product collection returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the  [Wordpress codex post about the WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) You will see a part which talks about Page and Posts Parameters. There you will see you can use the name parameter.

Assuming your product slug is chocolate-chip, you can use this to retrieve your product with the post_type and name parameters:

```
$itemArgs = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'name' => 'chocolate-chip'
    );
$query = new WP_Query($itemArgs);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$product_obj = get_page_by_path( $slug, OBJECT, 'product' );
```

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/206886/get-product-details-by-url-key-in-wordpress-woocommerce